# How many passes does Defrag take in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, defragment

How many passes does `Defrag.exe` take in Windows 10?

New laptop, and I started a while ago and it's now up to `Pass 14`

Comment: I have seen some systems do 15 passes before completion. Depends on how bad the fragmentation is. Consolidating free space seems to take the most time. Your 24 passes is a record breaker!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Disk Defragmenter might take from several minutes to a few hours to
> finish, depending on the size and degree of fragmentation of your hard
> disk. You can still use your computer during the defragmentation
> process.

Microsoft [never specifically says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-improve-your-computer-s-performance-c6018c78-0edd-a71a-7040-02267d68ea90), because Windows auto-detects the needed settings. The amount and time is different for every situation.

Comment: Blimey, I'm used to the old 2 or 3 passes, not this new stuff. Thanks for the info.

Comment: No problem. I should probably point out that Windows 10 manages files in a way that greatly reduces the need for defragmentation.

Comment: And in the end, it did 24 passes !!

Comment: "few hours" my foot ... here I'm at step 4 and time spent so far "only" 30 hours, but I needed it, surface test of the hdd and overall speed test GOOD but transfer speed both write and read was becoming really poor (3-5M/s down from the initially over 100M/s) so, defrag was the only idea I was thinking it may be the problem and first analyse was 75% fragmented (which I google and seems to be ... CRITICAL) and disk is (a laptop - 2.5") 1T with 50G free so I guess it may be right but still ... "few hours" my foot :P

Comment: @TheSourcerer You should clean up at least 100 gigs free - ideally 200 gigs - Windows takes a performance hit when your filesystem is > 80% full, which gets exponentially worse as it approaches 100%

Comment: "You can still use your computer during the defragmentation process." hahahaha... unless you are waiting for it to finish so you can shut it down (for instance, to move the computer somewhere else)!

Comment: @Ulincsys can you elaborate on your comment about the way Windows 10 manages files reducing the need for defragging? I have a 4tb HDD for storing video, music etc. The copy speed is terrible on there now and it said something like 98% fragmented (it's about 2 years old maybe 3)

Comment: @BigTLarrity certainly! Windows 10 (and all modern versions of Windows) requires installation to an NTFS formatted drive, which employs structures (such as the Master File Table) that reduce the impact of fragmentation relative to FAT file systems. Of course, this does not help for attached drives formatted with other file systems.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 8 and up auto-detects the number of passes required depending on the SMART status, number of errors, size of disk, time since last inspection, etc. You can keep it running in background and does not affect your performance much on a decently speced device. It can take anywhere from 1-2 passes to 40 passes and more to complete. There is no set amount of defrag. You can also manually set the passes required if you use third party tools. Ho much fragmented was your drive?

Comment: Can't remember the exact numbers, but it was a fresh installation on a new drive, so I'd assume not very fragmented

Answer (score 1):

Took me about 14 hours, at least 4 passes (each subsequent pass was significantly faster, might've been more than 4 passes but if so I missed seeing any passes above the 4th).

(1TB HDD, Windows 10, i5-8250U, laptop about 4 years old)